# Creating an empty dataframe with 50 columns with only 5 specific columns filled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe A that has 5 columns and a few 100 thousand rows. What I need is to create a dataframe B that has 50 columns with 45 of them empty and the other 5 filled with the data I have in dataframe A.

The reason I need it in this format is because I want to eventually covert to a csv file with a (,) delimiter and most of the columns empty.

My Dataframe A looks like this:

| id | order | first | last | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | Johnny | Depp | type1 |
| 2 | 222 | Amber | Heard | type2 |

my Dataframe B should look something like this with more empty columns at the end:

| x | order | first | last | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | type | x | x | x | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empty | 111 | Johnny | Depp | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | type1 | empty | empty | empty | empty |
| empty | 222 | Amber | Heard | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | empty | type2 | empty | empty | empty | empty |

As you can see I need to specify the position of the column for the `type` column. This is because I eventually want to convert to CSV with the function
`to_csv(delimiter=',')` which will eventually looks like this:

```
,111,Johnny,Depp,,,,,,,,,type1,,,,,
,222,Amber,Heard,,,,,,,,,type2,,,,,
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2], "order": [111, 222], "first": ["Johnny", "Amber"], "last": ["Depp", "Heard"], "type": ["type1", "type2"]})
push = ["x", "order", "first", "last"] + list("x" * 7) + ["type"] + list("x" * 4)
cols = [f"x{num}" if value == "x" else value for num, value in enumerate(push)]
b = pd.DataFrame({col: a[col] if col in a.columns.to_list() else None for col in cols})
print(b)
```

Seems like a fairly arbitrary problem, but I think this solves your specific request. Feel free to change the `"x" * 7` value to reflect your wishes. Also you can replace `None` with `np.nan` if you `import numpy as np`. Or you could replace `None` with `""` to insert empty strings. Your questions is a bit vague by stating "empty".

Output:

```
     x0  order   first   last    x4    x5    x6    x7    x8    x9   x10   type   x12   x13   x14   x15
0  None    111  Johnny   Depp  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  type1  None  None  None  None
1  None    222   Amber  Heard  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  type2  None  None  None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am assuming dataframe B already has the the first 5 columns filled with the data you need.

You can then just make a loop to add however many blank columns you want:

```
i=4 # However many columns the df started with

while i < 50: # or however many blank columns you want to add
    df[f'column_{i}'] = ''
    i+=1
```

Comment: it doesnt unfortunately, the Dataframe B is what I want to create from Dataframe A @yeff

Comment: You can create `df_b = df[['id','order','first','last','type']]`
Then you run the loop, then you can add `df_b['type'] = df['type']` as the last column